# Spring cloud stream how to test custom Source and Output

Tags: spring-boot, mockito, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream, spring-boot-test

Spring cloud stream how to test custom Source and Output?

```
public interface DeviceManagerOutput {
   String OUTPUT = "deviceManager";

   @Output( DeviceManagerOutput.OUTPUT )
   MessageChannel output();
}

@Service
@EnableBinding( DeviceManagerOutput.class )
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class DeviceManagerSink {
   private final DeviceManagerOutput source;

   @ServiceActivator( outputChannel = DeviceManagerOutput.OUTPUT )
   @LogName
   public void sendDeviceManagerUpdate( String message ) {
      source.output().send( new GenericMessage<>( message ) )
   }

}
```

**MessageSender.java**

```
@Slf4j
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class MessageSender {
  private final DeviceManagerSink deviceManagerSink;

  public void sendMessage(String message) {
    route(message);
  }

  @Override
  @LogName
  public void route( String message ) {
      log.info( "Ingoring the Source provide.. using another source for configuration message.." );
      this.deviceManagerSink.sendDeviceManagerUpdate( message );
   }
}
```

How can I test whether call to MessageChannel send method is successful or not?

Test Class

```
@RunWith( MockitoJUnitRunner.class )
public class MessageSenderTest {

    @Mock
    private MessageSender messageSender;

    @Mock
    private DeviceManagerSink deviceManagerSink;

    @Test
    public void test_route_message() {
        this.messageSender.sendMessage("Hi");
        verify( deviceManagerSink, times( 1 ) ).sendDeviceManagerUpdate( any() ); // gives success    
}
```

inside sendDeviceManagerUpdate we are calling send method of DeviceManagerOutput. How to test if call to send method is successful or not?

Comment: May I ask why do you have a custom binding for something that `Source.class` binding would work?

Comment: also, you don't need to test if ` a call to MessageChannel send method is successful or not?` since this is the contract of the framework. If it is not sent then it's a bug on our end. What you should test is the functionality of your method in isolation.

Comment: Plus; since your test `MessageSender` is a `@Mock`, the real sender will never be called.